# How can I charge my merchants (clients) a percent per transaction when their buyers pay them on PayPal?

Tags: transactions, paypal, markup

I have an e-commerce SaaS offering where merchants can come and open their online stores automatically, pretty similar to Shopify.
When buyers make transactions on my clients (merchants) stores, how can I charge merchant a certain percent and transfer it to my account?
I went through Adaptive Payment APIs and it seems like it is doable. However, I'm using Express Checkout for buyers to pay merchants.
On the other hand, there is parallel payment in Express Checkout but it shows the buyer in the transaction details that he is gonna pay me in addition to the merchant.
I want this to be transparent to the buyers where they see that they are paying to the merchant only, and in the background I get a parecent.
I don't know how Shopify is able to use Express Checkout and charge a markup on every transaction happens on their merchant sites.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have your users setup a preapproval profile with you using the [Preapproval API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/preapproval-api-operation).  This will allow you to make [Pay](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/pay-api-operation) calls using the preapproval key so the payment will happen immediately without any additional login or approval.

You could then either tie the Pay calls to pay yourself your percentage within the Express Checkout flow, or you could do that within [IPN](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro), which would probably be the better place to do it.  That way you won't pay yourself on e-checks until they actually clear, for example.

The result would be that your user sees their total amount paid to them, and then immediately after that they see the amount they owe you paid to you automatically.